# Unity main character falls down when getting close to a corner

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I'm trying to create a game in Unity 2D. I've created the player movement but now I have the problem that when I get close to corner the sprite starts falling down and rotates.

It gets like in this image [image]

Answer (score 0):

In your **Rigidbody2D** expand the Constraints menu and freeze the rotation on z